# how to tell org mode to make subsequent lines children of the hierarchy

Tags: org-mode, outline-mode

I have a list like this:

```
remember to undo:
product 0 discrimination
limit(100)
ENV['MANUAL_...']
```

When point is at the beginning of line 1, how can I tell org mode
to make subsequent lines children of the hierarchy, like this

```
remember to undo:
  product 0 discrimination
  limit(100)
  ENV['MANUAL_...']
```

I don't even mind this

```
remember to undo:
  - product 0 discrimination
  - limit(100)
  - ENV['MANUAL_...']
```

or this

```
remember to undo:
  [ ] product 0 discrimination
  [ ] limit(100)
  [ ] ENV['MANUAL_...']
```

or even asterisks

Answer (score 1):

1. If you only want to modify a part of your text select the relevant region otherwise put point at the beginning of the first line.
2. Replace the empty string at the line-beginning with the string consisting of one star and one space <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> `^` <kbd>RET</kbd> `*⎵` <kbd>RET</kbd> (thereby the char `⎵` stands for a space).
3. Select the lines below the first one and demote the headings with <kbd>M-right</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a command that does that until it finds an empty line:

```
(defun indent-children ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (while (looking-at ".*[^\n[:space:]]")
      (forward-line 1)
      (indent-to 2))))
```